# What's the Best Way to Lose Fat and Keep Muscle?

Tags: weight-loss, diet, muscle-gain

I've been through countless types of workout routines, diet plans, detoxes and the works. The best type of workout I've used is Cross Training and I'm on a low carb, high protein, high fiber, high vitamin and mineral diet. I know I am following correct and healthy routines because I'm also educated in Biology and a bit of nutrition. But somehow, I don't ever seem to get past a certain point of fat percentage and then I hit a wall. Is there something I'm missing? And what are some tips to losing fat in a healthy way and still retaining the muscle I have?

Comment: Just to clarify, the wall that I hit almost every time is around 16% body fat.

Answer (score 1):

Insulin causes fat cells to store free floating fat from the blood. Unless you have an endocrine disorder, you will become more insulin sensitive the lower your bodyfat goes.

Going from 25% body fat to 20% is fairly straightforward.  Going from 10% to 5% is *much* harder.

Your body is trying to store every last nugget of energy at lower bf levels.

You can bust through body fat walls, but they will progressively require tighter and tighter discipline.  Age and hormone levels are also important.

Answer (score 0):

Bring your 'diet' up to that point, the wall.

Ketogenic dieting will get you past it, strict <30g net carbs daily & a caloric deficit and you will arrive at your destination.

It's not healthy in the long term but seeing as the diet is pretty much nothing but Protein and Fat you'd have a hard time atrophying your muscles for fuel.

Ensure you calculate your TDEE (a weighted average is best) before developing your food plan.